# Javascript for showing/hiding flagged options in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

I am trying to write a Javascript for a drop down menu on my JSP page. Basically, The drop down retrieves a bunch of options from a database query, and the options are sorted by a flag in the query (1 or 0). So the options at the top of the dropdown menu are all the options with 1, and below that are all the options with 0.

What I would like to do is only show the options flagged as 1 upon clicking on the dropdown, and then at the bottom of that list of options, have a "show hidden options" option that the user can click to show the rest of the options (the ones flagged as 0).

Does anyone have any ideas for how to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: could you post the code ?

Comment: I think you would need a custom [jQuery UI widget](https://jqueryui.com/widget/).  I've only had to slightly modify one someone else wrote, so I have no idea how to go about doing what you need.

Comment: Doesn't sound too difficult, load in the options with the 0 flag with a CSS class that hides them, then write an event handler on click, maybe jQuery slideDown() on the "show hidden options" button that will display those with the 0 flag.  Like @DinoMyte says, you should post your code that shows what you have done already to solve it.